# C++ class template specialize variable

Tags: c++, templates, conditional-statements

I have **`Pool`** class template, lets say something like these:

```
template <class T>
class Pool {
public:
    static int iPoolUpperBound;
    static int iPoolSize;
    static T **pItem;
    T();
    ~T();
}
```

When i need objects pool for a certain class i just use that template. I also have **`Item`** class, and i need to add vector to current **`Pool`** template, but that vector should be only present if im referring/using **`Item`** class.

Simple `if (T == Item)` wont work that's obvious, and i already gave my best to conditionally add that vector to `Pool` template

It would be also helpful if i could conditionally add line or two in **`Pool`** class template member function without overloading it.

Comment: I don't get your question, sorry. Do you want to create a pool for `T` items that can be created using _placement `new()`_? What problem do you actually want to solve. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44170172/edit) your question please, we can't read your brain.

Comment: If they differ like that, it can hardly be called a template, right? But why don't you simply go with `class SpecialPool : public Pool<Item> { vector<someType> vec; }`? That would be in the right spirit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It would be also helpful if i could conditionally add line or two in Pool class template member function without overloading it.

By example, you can overload only `pItem`.

```
struct Item
 { };

template <typename>
struct proItem
 { };

template <>
struct proItem<Item>
 { static Item ** pItem; };

Item ** proItem<Item>::pItem;

template <typename T>
struct Pool : public proItem<T>
 {
   static int iPoolUpperBound;
   static int iPoolSize;
 };


int main()
 {
   Pool<Item>::pItem = nullptr;   // compile
   //Pool<int>::pItem = nullptr;  // compilation error
 }
```